Define something based on the property of another set.
I have always been confused about a logic problem, which I can not form it into a general statement. Here is an example that may express my ideas.
We know given a set $A$ and an equivalent relation $\sim$ on it. We can define equivalence class by $\forall x\in A, [x]=\{y,|y \sim x\}$. It seems to me the equivalence class is always non-empty, since $x \in [x]$, but is it heavily reliable on the fact that $A$ is not empty? If $A$ is empty, then can we still define the equivalence class in this way? Is it vacuously true?
If not. Does that mean if we need to define something, no matter a set or a function in this way ($\forall x \in D$, define $C_x$ or $f_x$), we should always guarantee $D$ is not empty?

If you just had a general relation of $A$, as opposed to an equivalence relation, you could define $[x]$ the same way only now it would be possible for $[x]=\emptyset$   (it would also be possible that we could find $y,z\in [x]$ but $y\not \sim z$, and you'd want to distinguish left and right versions).  I don't see a problem with that.

Can you explain a little? I am confused about your comments.

Given a set $A$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$, then for all $x\in A$, the equivalence class $[x]$ is not empty.  You don't have to make any special exception for $A$ being empty... the "for all" statement is vacuously true in that case, and there are zero equivalence classes in the quotient $A/\sim$.

I am offering a natural, in context, example of a parallel situation in which $[x]=\emptyset$, even if $A\neq \emptyset$.  If $A=\emptyset$ then of course the definition is empty since the desired equivalence is never satisfied.

@ mjqxxxx. I think my question is more about if $A$ is empty, can we still define equivalence class in this way, i.e. $\forall x \in D, [x]= $ blabla?

A definition is not true or false. It's a shortcut or alias for a commonly used meaning.
So yes, even if $A$ might be empty, we can define that for an element $x \in A$, "the equivalence class of $x$" or "$[x]$" means the set $\{y \in A \mid y \sim x\}$.
Here $A$ is sort of a "domain" for the definition, just for remembering what sorts of inputs make sense for the definition. A definition's parameters don't always need domains like formal functions or set-builder notations do. A definition's informal "domain" helps understand the definition's meaning in the first place, and sometimes just using the definition can imply its parameters are in that domain. (We can understand "$x \in [y] \Leftrightarrow y \in [x]$" means $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$, but it would be clearer to say so.)
Then the statement "no equivalence class is empty" is true, whether or not $A$ is empty: more formally, this says
$$ \forall x \in A .([x] \neq \emptyset) $$
which is the same as
$$ \forall x \in A .(\{y \in A \mid y \sim x\} \neq \emptyset) $$
These are true since $(x \in A) \Rightarrow (x \sim x) \Rightarrow (x \in [x]) \Rightarrow ([x] \neq \emptyset)$. Here too we could write out what each $[x]$ means, just making the proof longer and harder to read. If $A$ is empty, the statement is vacuously true. But the logical evaluation, vacuous or not, doesn't really relate to the definition, and the definition isn't really itself affected by whether its "domain" is empty.
Sometimes we define something as the unique element satisfying some property or properties relative to some parameters, with a proof that the element is in fact unique. In this case, we can formalize the definition by using the proof of uniqueness to prove a function exists, and then use of the defined name or symbol is just referencing that function which does exist.
I would avoid using the symbol $\forall$ in the phrasing "for all $x \in D$, define set $C_x$ and function $f_x$". The $\forall$ symbol usually introduces a true or false proposition, and a definition is not such a thing.

Could you please explain why even if $A$ is empty, we can still define the equivalence class in this way? That what makes me confused. Another example may be the preimage of a function $f^{-1} (A) ={x \in X \mid f(x) \in A}$, which still I think is heavily reliable on $f$ is not the empty function?

It's like I can say "for any unicorn $u$, define $C_u$ to be the color of the tip of $u$'s horn". The definition itself isn't invalid or true or false. If there are no unicorns, that means many statements involving $C_u$ are vacuously true or false. And without even knowing for sure if any do exist, we can make some valid deductions and statements using $C_u$.

If $X$ is empty OR $A$ is empty, then $f^{-1}(A) = {x \in X \mid f(x) \in A}$ is an empty set. $f^{-1}(A)$ still means what it does.

A statement like: $$\forall x\in A [P(x)]$$ is actually an abbreviation for:$$\forall x [x\in A\to P(x)]$$or equivalently:$$\forall x [x\notin A\vee P(x)]\tag1$$
Now note that for every $x$ it is true that:$$x\notin\varnothing$$ hence also that:$$x\notin\varnothing\vee P(x)$$
So statement $(1)$ is a true statement if $A=\varnothing$ (no matter what is stated by $P(x)$).

If $A$ is the empty set, then $\forall x \in A \text{    } x \in [x]$ is vacuously true.
